# Cypress failed test video recording fails to process

Tags: cypress

After hundreds of runs searching for test instability, my videos suddenly started failing to process. Nothing has changed from what I can find, and it worked all day up until recently. Rather than going through the compression, it just completes immediately, and reviewing the video shows the proper length of the run but the recording only shows black. Normally it takes about 30-45 seconds to compress.

Using debug tools from this section of the Wiki: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/screenshots-and-videos.html#Video-encoding

I was able to come across this

```
cypress:server:video compression stderr log { message: '[ffmetadata @ 0x7ffe11800000] Expected chapter end timestamp, found END=null.' } +5ms
```

After this all other processes for the compresson takes +0 ms, which I think means they are being skipped

```
cypress:server:video compression stderr log { message: '[mp4 @ 0x7ffe12804000] Application provided duration: -264 / timestamp: 13737 is out of range for mov/mp4 format' } +0ms
cypress:server:video compression stderr log { message: '[mp4 @ 0x7ffe12804000] pts has no value' } +0ms
```

Running on a Macbook Pro

[image: console output]

Comment: Maybe you can force the compression by using `"videoCompression": true` in your `cypress.json` file

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. `"videoCompression": true` is not a viable option, it either has to be false or a number. It did give me another avenue to investigate, so I did try using different options here, none of which succeed. Just gonna keep digging I suppose.